# Symfony2 multiple databases, specify database for each table

Tags: database, symfony, connection

The problem is that I have 2 + databases defined in Symfony. And when I update table schema with

```
php app/console dotrine:schema:update --force
```

it makes the tables in the default database. I'd like to specify which database the table belongs to. How could i do that?

I'm using yaml(yml) format for the entities, example:

```
Test\ExampleBundle\Entity\TestTable:
    type: entity
    table: test_table
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        sound:
            type: smallint
```

Comment: This from the docs might help - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a deeper look at [How to work with Multiple Entity Managers and Connections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) section of the documentation.

Doctrine offers you the ability to have multiple connections. You can easily add entity managers to bind your entities to different predefined connections according to the bundles they belong to.

According to the documentation, you can bind bundles to entity managers, but here is **A trick** on how to use two entity managers in the same bundle,

If you want to bind entities from one bundle to different entity managers you can add a "dir" attribute to define a path to a specific entities folder.

Example,

```
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                MyBundle:
                    dir:      Path/To/EntityFolder1
        myManager:
            connection:       myConnection
            mappings:
                MyBundle:
                    dir:      Path/To/EntityFolder2
```

You can then put your bundle entities into the right folders according to the connection they are bound to.

Comment: I tried this, but the documents u linked me to are 1.2 version and I'm using 2.0 and this is not working.

Comment: How about if I have 2 different databases for 1 bundle? And it has to know what table belongs to what database.

Comment: Ah thanks, I updated my answer. 
I don't think you can use two entity managers in one bundle, otherwise you can have a separate bundles for your entities.

Comment: I updated my answer, just try the trick I added and let me know if it works fine for you? and if this approach can help you manage your entities?

Comment: So since I use 2 databases for the tables, can I somehow seperate the table definitions, so I can make it like that? I managed to get all of the tables to the other database, but now I have to seperate the table definitions for each database. Is there any predefined way to seperate them?

Comment: Why don't you just create the right entities in the right entity folder and let them be mapped to the right database based on the config code snippet I gave you. Why do you need to define your tables the old way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19482/discussion-between-ahmed-siouani-and-n00b)